# Unspecified padding with border-box sizing

Tags: css

I noticed something odd with my CSS earlier. As you can see in my image below, I have a `td` element with `padding` set to 0. However, if you look to the left, you can see the green-tinted areas where there's about 10px of padding on the top and bottom, even thought Chrome says there is no padding. I didn't write the CSS, but I discovered that setting the `box-sizing` property to `border-box` is what seems to be causing this. But I can't really figure out how to get rid of it.

So where is this phantom padding coming from, and how can I get rid of it while still using `border-box` sizing?

[image]

EDIT: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ngr66/2/) is a Fiddle that should demonstrate the behavior (at least in the latest version of Chrome). I can't figure out how to get rid of the padding unless I do something like `table * { box-sizing: content-box; }`, which I don't want to do.

Comment: I'm not seeing any evidence of padding.  The tinted area is always that size, it's just making room for the numbers and label.  Does the table have `cellpadding` or `cellspacing` set?

Comment: Look on the left and you'll see a green bar on the top and bottom. That's padding that exists on the actual page.

Comment: Can you post your code and a fiddle?

Comment: It's company code, so I can't post the whole thing, but I'll take a stab a creating a fiddle.

Comment: Doh! I missed it just like I missed my morning coffee.

Comment: I see `box-sizing` declared on line 61

Comment: I want `box-sizing: border-box` declared. What I don't want is the phantom padding that is being added because of it.

Comment: I think your .details-body class got padding and in my fiddle I can see it on td element

Comment: That is it, but why is affecting the padding on the `td` element?